# How to load a model in tensorflow python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/BEENU MAM/Downloads/face-recognization/face-recognization/gender-detection/gender_detection.py", line 10, in 
model = load_model("gender_detection_pre.model")
File "C:\Users\BEENU MAM\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 149, in load_model
loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath)
File "C:\Users\BEENU MAM\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 83, in parse_saved_model
constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PB))
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: gender_detection_pre.model/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

I supose by your traceback that your model is stored somewhere in:

```
gender_detection_pre/model
```

To avoid the error in Tensorflow you just need to set the folder of the model as model path when loading it with keras.

Something like this:

```
keras.models.load_model(gender_detection_model)
```

Because keras actually searches for the model inside the folder you pass as path.